# typescript Promise : 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, promise

i have created below code to get some data, i am returning that data in a function and i am calling that function in a variable like below :

```
 let tmsValue = await GetTMS(fymcl,this.model); 
    console.log("tmsValue",tmsValue);

   let tms;
   var GetTMS = async function getTMS(yearMetricCombo, modelData) : Promise<any>{
     return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     modelData
       .query("11111")
       .where("fymcl").equals(yearMetricCombo) // tm|FY18|Promtions
       .loadAll()
       .exec((error, data) => {
         if (error) {
           reject(error);
         } else {
           tms = String(data.Items[0].attrs.uploadtms);
           resolve(tms);
           // console.log("tms",tms); // iam getting value over here
         }
       });
       return tms;
     });
   }
```

The issue is  `let tmsValue = await GetTMS(fymcl,this.model);  // this line is saying 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.`

I am not sure what i need to do.

Comment: Your function `GetTMS` has no return statement, so the function implicitly returns `undefined`. It looks like it's making an asynchronous db call, so you may want to look into using a `Promise` here. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i have updated with a promise

Comment: But now its saying await can only be used inside async function

Comment: Indeed, the `await` keyword can only be used in a function declared with the `async` keyword. That means it cannot appear at the root level of your file. If you need to use the `getTMS` function at the root of the file, you'll have to put the code that uses its result inside the `.then` callback of the promise. If you need to use `getTMS` in another function, you either need to use the `.then` method as mentioned, or mark the function as `async`.

Comment: i have marked it as async, can u please make some update in my code to include .then()

Comment: You can only use `await` INSIDE a function declared with the `async` keyword.  That's a core requirement of the language feature.  Please go back and read the basics about `async` and `await`.  There are hundreds of articles on this topic.  You don't even show the containing function for your `await GetTMS()` so we can't advise any more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't return:

```
 function GetTMS(yearMetricCombo, modelData){
      // NO RETURN STATEMENT HERE
      modelData
      .query("11111")
      .where("fymcl").equals(yearMetricCombo) // tm|FY18|Promtions
      .loadAll()
      .exec((error, data) => {
        console.log("error",error);
        if (error) {
        } else {
          let tms = String(data.Items[0].attrs.uploadtms);
          console.log("tms",tms);
          // this returns from the *arrow function*, not
          // the enclosing function declaration
          return tms;

        }
      });
      // NO RETURN STATEMENT HERE
    }
```

See the question linked to from @CRice's comment for how to return from an async call

Comment: why i need a return statement at the top ?

Comment: You don't, I'm just listing the two places where a `return` statement could be but isn't

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the OP's error they asked about.  The OP's error is because they're trying to use `await` outside of an `async` defined function which you cannot do.  That's a core requirement of using `await`.

Comment: OP has been substantially edited since I posted this :\